# To "pull" or "push" diverged branches after a rebase?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I've had an outdated, but clean `test` branch which I rebased against `master`. After resolving a few conflicts, I successfully finished a rebase process. However, `git status` now tells me that branches `test` and `origin/test` have diverged, `and have 37 and 15 different commits each, respectively.` I'd like to sync the branches after the rebase process, so I planned to do a `push`, but not sure anymore, I don't understand the logic behind the "37 and 15 different commits".

What should be the next step, `pull` or `push`?

Comment: Rebase *copies* old commits to new and (one may hope) improved *replacement* commits. The different commits are the old ones, and the new ones. If you run `git pull` you're telling Git to fetch the old commits and then *merge* them with your new replacements, giving you the worst of both worlds, so you definitely *don't* want to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to force-push your `test` branch.

Before the rebase, you had this situation:

```
--o-- 21 more commits --o     master
   \
    o-- 13 more commits --o   test and origin/test
```

After your rebase, you have this situation:

```
--o-- 21 more commits --o                          master
   \                     \
    \                     o-- 13 more commits --o  test
     \
      o-- 13 more commits --o                      origin/test
```

That is, you left `origin/test` behind because you built your own branch on top of `master`. `master` had 22 commits, and you built your 15 commits on top, that gives 37 commits. `origin/test` remains at its 15 commits. And that is why `git status` reports "37 and 15 different commits".

At this point, you most likely want to publish your `test` branch, i.e. push it to your remote repository. You have to force-push because the new head (`test`) is no longer a descendent of `origin/test`.

Comment: Should I have done a merge instead of a rebase? I'd like to avoid a force push. Overall, what's the proper workflow?

Comment: If you cannot afford a force-push, you should reset `test` to `origin/test` and do a merge.

Comment: **"Proper workflow" is in the eye of the beholder.** Use whatever suits you best. *I* prefer topic branches and merges, but the resulting history may look like a mess to an outsider (and to myself, too, at some times). I can understand that others prefer a linear history and rebase their branches frequently.

Comment: Does rebase always result in a `force push`, in other words, have I done everything properly?

Comment: Yes, after a rebase you always have to force-push the resulting branch. You did everything correctly (if my assumptions about your branch states are correct).

Comment: OK, so this scenario is OK if you haven't yet pushed your branch to origin, i.e. if you are not sharing it. Otherwise, force-push might hurt other people...

Comment: @Danijel Correct!